# C# method failing to function for no known reason

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm currently taking a programming class and learning C#. One of my assignments was to have a program run with a graphical user interface that has a text box for input, a text box for output, and a button that copies whatever number was in the "input" text box and pastes it into the output text box. For some reason the method `computeBtn_Click`, which was the method to read the number in the input and put that in the output, was doing absolutely nothing for me, but by using the method name `computeBtn_Click_1` it worked great. Any idea why?

Here is my code(without all the using.System stuff):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //exitToolStripMenuItem1 method
        //Purpose: To close the window and terminate the application.
        //Parameters: The object generating the event and the event arguments.
        //Returns: None
        void exitToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        //aboutToolStripMenu method
        //Purpose: To give information about the application.
        //Parameters: The object generating the event and the event arguments.
        //Returns: None
        void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name\nCS1400\nLab #4");
        }

        private void inTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void outTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // For some reason this method wasn't working.
        // computeBtn_Click Method
        // Purpose: Get a value from the user and display it back again
        // Parameters: The sending object, and the event arguments
        // Returns: none
        /*private void computeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num = int.Parse(inTxtBox.Text);
            string outStr = string.Format("{0:D}", num);
            outTxtBox.Text = outStr;
        }*/

        // computeBtn_Click_1 Method
        // Purpose: Get a value from the user and display it back again
        // Parameters: The sending object, and the event arguments
        // Returns: none
        private void computeBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num = int.Parse(inTxtBox.Text);
            string outStr = string.Format("{0:D}", num);
            outTxtBox.Text = outStr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet you used to have a button of the same name that was, at one time, deleted. When you added another button of the same name it created a new name with the index/subscript. Thank you auto-generated code.

Comment: Is the computeBtn Click event hooked up to that control (look at the Events tab of the properties window of the control)

Comment: You are randomly adding event handlers.  Be careful with that double-click.  Learn how to use the Properties window, click on the lightning-bolt icon to see the event handlers.

Comment: Got it. After checking the Click property in Events it was set to computeBtn_Click_1. Also, this is an assignment that I did a while back and have since stopped adding events handlers for everything in the form. At the time I thought that I had to do it for the text boxes too because I got an error that I thought was related somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create event handlers Visual Studio assigns names automatically. So in your case you have a button named `computeBtn`. Then in the graphical designer you create an event handler for the Click event. VS automatically creates name for it: `computeBtn_Click`.

Now if in the graphical designer you decide to remove the event handler (e.g. in Properties tab for the button) nothing is hooked to the Click event but the method named `computeBtn_Click` remained in the class. So what will happen if you decide to create an event handler for the Click event? IDE will create a new method and since there is already something with the name `computeBtn_Click` it will modify name of the new method so it is still unique. Which in this case results in `computeBtn_Click_1`.

To confirm that, you can check references of the method that does not work. It will show that there are no references in the code to the method. To check the references click the method's name and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> or use context menu.

Comment: After checking the Click property in Events it was set to computeBtn_Click_1. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers are great, but I thought I might add another easy way to avoid this. When you select your button in the designer, go to the properties window, there you'll find a tab called "Events". Under "Click", you can select the method you wish to use for the button's click event.

Answer (score 1):

your `EventHandler`  delegate  is  not set in  your partial class to call `computeBtn_Click`
by partial class I  mean the `Form1.Designer.cs`  which may look like  this

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 30);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 74);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.computeBtn_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

try this  and your method will  be called when you  click the  button

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(computeBtn_Click);
        }
```